# How do I connect surface wireway to a breaker box?

Tags: electrical, nec

I am running Legrand/Wiremold 4000 series for a garage shop. The instructions for the panel connector (4086A) consist of a tiny picture that implies all I need to do is cut a large square hole in my breaker box and bolt in the adapter. Is this allowed? I can not find a second source to confirm this and I am hesitant to carve up the box.

Comment: I take it the breaker box in question is an indoor (NEMA 1) box that is surface mounted, right?

Comment: Also, are you trying to come into the box from the top/bottom, or from one side?

Comment: Honestly, I would cap the surface raceway system wherever convenient  (e.g. with a 4010B or 4010DFO which provides a sizable junction box) and come the rest of the way with EMT through a standard knockout. Problem solved, you just have to switch crafts for a few feet.  It also doesn't leave a gaping hole in your panel if you ever go with a different system.

Comment: Yes, it is an indoor, surface mount box. It is bottom fed, so I was planning to come in from the side. I considered using conduit but when I found the panel connector I thought it would make for a more elegant installation. I assumed there would be more documentation.

Comment: How many wires are you trying to pull through this wireway, and what size are they?

Comment: Hello ThreePhaseEel. I am planning on thirty 12AWG wires, and six 8AWG of THHN in an undivided channel. Approximately half of the listed capacity using 1.59 square inch duplex receptacles. The clerk of my local electrician's supply shop basically told me to stop being a wuss and just cut the darn hole. If inspections were as cheap as boxes then I would probably not be so cautious. I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: @JamesSaxon how many of those wires count as current-carrying conductors? (if all 36 do, then you'll be absolutely *screwed* on derating factors...)

Comment: If less than 30 current carrying and the wire way is less than 20% filled it could be considered a gutter and no derate would be required.